# Button to open Invisible Frame

Tags: html, css

I want a button to open an iframe. I've experimented with various forms of onclick, but I'm missing the secret to put these two pieces of code together.

```
<button type="button">Test</button>
<iframe style="visibility:hidden;display:none" src="example.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this works perfectly:

```
<iframe style="display:none;" name="some"/>

<form method="GET" target="some">
    <button type="submit" formaction="choice1.com">Choice1</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="choice2.com">Choice2</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an id :)

Try the following code : 
Even if it's better to make a real js functon ;)

This just diplay the iframe Preloaded

```
<button type="button" onclick="var a = document.getElementById('myIframe');a.style.display='block'">Test</button>
<iframe id="myIframe" style="width:100px;height:100px;display:none" src="google.com"></iframe>
```

this display the iframe and load it :

```
<button type="button" onclick="var a = document.getElementById('myIframe');a.src='http://google.com';a.style.display='block'">Test</button>
<iframe id="myIframe" style="width:100px;height:100px;display:none" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: That's not working. It executes the iframe on loading the page, and not on button click.

Comment: @RichardU Oh you don't want to load the iframe before the click?

Comment: Correct. I want to load the iframe on every click of the button only. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. I tried the second bit of code. That's not working either. Must be missing something.

Comment: @RichardU

https://jsfiddle.net/Crocsx/zg79kLz2/1/

(it doesn't load the iframe cause it's unsecure on jsfiddle blabla" but if your only goal is to show the iframe. the code work and it will work on your website.

Can you show a demo of what you have and explain concretely what you expect?

Comment: First, thanks for helping me with this. I have a server I need to hit. The URL is: "http://xxx.domain.org:1234/Param?1=70." When I replace "google.com" with that in your original code, the server responds as needed when the page is loaded, but not when the button is pushed. When I replace "google.com" in the second code example. Nothing happens, either when the page is loaded or when the button is pressed.

Comment: I tried both variants on the jsfiddle. The button changes the src for iframe, but it is not causing the iframe to execute a GET to my server.

Comment: Your main topic isn't complete so. We lack of informations.

What do you really want? My solutions are what you need to load a static page inside an iframe and show it when you click on a button. That's what you asked on the main post.

Now, what you said above makes me think you want to make an ajax call to a server, or something else that i don't get :3 sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to create the iframe on the button click as well and then append to the DOM.
On click function of button create iframe node and define its src and append it to DOM

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've been trying to do.

Comment: @RichardU If your query has been resolved, accept the answer

Comment: It is resolved in theory. However it is the same theory I started with. My question is really the code required to accomplish that theory.